# RSpec error: Factory not registered after migrate from FactoryGirl to FactoryBot

Tags: factory-bot

After migrate the factory FactoryGirl to FactoryBot, using the quick migration [instructions](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/v4.9.0/UPGRADE_FROM_FACTORY_GIRL.md), I got errors in my tests in RSpec regarding to factory registration.

```
ArgumentError:
   Factory not registered: user
```

Answer (score 0):

After digging a lot, I found the solution [here](https://makandracards.com/rails_cheat_sheets/48119-common-factorybot-gotchas).

Include the following code in `spec_helper.rb`

```
config.before(:all) do
    FactoryBot.reload
end
```